# Adobe Air - Detect app is in the background without using permissions?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have created an app using adobe Flash CS6 / Adobe Air 26.0 .

To pause the game whenever the app goes into background, I'm using the Deactivate state correctly, and everything is working fine.

I needed to add permission through the xml file to read the phone state `READ_PHONE_STATE`.

I understand that this permission also implies that the app is reading the phone's phone number, log and several other stuff, that's why I had to create a privacy policy.

Is there any other permission that I could use instead of `READ_PHONE_STATE` since I only need to know if the app is going to the background, and I don't need all the other stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to detect if your app went to the background or came back to the foreground you would have to use the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission. This permission is added automatically by Adobe AIR when you use the following events.

Detecting it is done by adding event listeners for deactivating and re-activating the app:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, onDeactivate);
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, onActivate);

function onDeactivate(evt:Event):void
{
   // Pause the game
}
function onActivate(evt:Event):void
{
   // Un-Pause the game
}
```

- The `Event.DEACTIVATE` event is fired when the app goes to the
  background.
- The `Event.ACTIVATE` event is fired when the app goes to
  the foreground.

The `READ_PHONE_STATE` is the most common permission and is used by most apps today.

The big advantage of Adobe AIR is that it runs the same on all mobile OS. The code above will let you know when a user exits or minimizes the app without the need of permissions for both Android and iOS devices.

Comment: The app is to be played on both Android and iOS phones, do you suggest that your way could achieve this result?

Comment: If anyone calls the user while using the app, could your code work and pause the game?

Comment: i'll try it later on and get back to you, thank you for your reply

Comment: A question, what will i use as an event listener to catch the app coming back from the background, in order to unpause it? Currently, i use "deactivate" to go to the background, and "activate" to catch it back. In your example, both events refer to closing or exiting, but how can i catch the coming back of the app?

Comment: @EliasRahme I've done some home work and tested it myself - see updated answer. You should use the `Event.DEACTIVATE` and `Event.ACTIVATE` events.

Comment: exactly, and this is what i'm using currently, but to use it you need to add permissions the READ_PHONE_STATE, which could imply the reading of the users log, phone numbers and all.. This is what i'm trying to avoid, is there any other way ?

Comment: @EliasRahme I see what you're saying... Yeah you have to use the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission for that. I see now that it was added automatically, I wasn't aware of it since it's a basic permission all apps use. I will update the answer accordingly.